# Recursive implementation of Fibonacci function

Tags: c, recursion, compiler-errors

I have written code to find both the Fibonacci number & the number of times the call is made to find the same for the recursive version in C. I am unable to remove compilation errors. Please help.

The code is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int fib) {
  int n,m, count=0; //'count' counts #times function is called
  printf("enter n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  return fib_rec(n, &count);
}

int fib_rec(int n, int *count)
{
  int b=0,c=1;
  *count = *count +1;
  if(n<=1)
  { 
    return n;
  }
  else
  {
    printf (count);
    return fib_rec(n-1, *count)+ fib_rec(n-2, *count);
  }
}
```

The compilation errors are given below upon running on reptl.it site, as shown.

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:7:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fib_rec' [- 
Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   return fib_rec(n, &count);
      ^~~~~~~
main.c: In function 'fib_rec':
main.c:20:13: warning: passing argument 1 of 'printf' from incompatible 
pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   printf (count);
         ^~~~~
In file included from main.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:364:43: note: expected 'const char * restrict' but 
argument is of type 'int *'
   extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
main.c:21:25: warning: passing argument 2 of 'fib_rec' makes pointer from 
integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   return fib_rec(n-1, *count)+ fib_rec(n-2, *count);
                     ^~~~~~
main.c:10:25: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'
   int fib_rec(int n, int *count)
                ~~~~~^~~~~
main.c:21:47: warning: passing argument 2 of 'fib_rec' makes pointer from 
integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   return fib_rec(n-1, *count)+ fib_rec(n-2, *count);
                                           ^~~~~~
main.c:10:25: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'
  int fib_rec(int n, int *count)
                ~~~~~^~~~~
enter n 10
exit status -1
>
```

Comment: Don't you think a data type is missing on line `7`?

Comment: Don't post image of error, text is enough.

Comment: Please copy-paste the errors (as text) into the question. And please don't add line-numbers to code (as it makes it harder for us to try it out ourselves).

Comment: (1) You need to declare `count` in `main`, i.e. `int count` (2) You need a forward declaration for function `fib_rec` before calling it (3) In `fib_rec`, add a format string to the `printf` call.

Comment: @TomKarzes Please elaborate by an answer, as am unable to pick the 2nd 
& 3rd clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pasted your code on https://tio.run/#c-gcc, and here's the result:

#### `main` prototype

```
.code.tio.c:3:7: warning: ‘main’ takes only zero or two arguments [-Wmain]
   int main(int fib) {
       ^~~~
```

the `main` function prototype is `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Since you want user to input a number, you can choose the first form.

#### `count` type

```
.code.tio.c: In function ‘main’:
.code.tio.c:7:5: error: ‘count’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     count = 0;  // counts the number of times the function is called
     ^~~~~
```

You must give a type to `count` variable, like

```
int count = 0;
```

#### `fib_rec` declaration

```
.code.tio.c:8:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fib_rec’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     return fib_rec(n, &count);
            ^~~~~~~
```

You have not declared the function before using it.

You can declare it this way: `int fib_rec(int n, int *count)` for instance before the `main` definition.

#### `printf` usage

```
.code.tio.c: In function ‘fib_rec’:
.code.tio.c:21:15: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
       printf (count);
               ^~~~~
```

The `printf` function ask for some formatting. If you want to display a integer value, use `%d`:

```
printf("count value is: %d\n", count);
```

#### incompatible pointer type

```
.code.tio.c:22:27: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fib_rec’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       return fib_rec(n-1, *count)+ fib_rec(n-2, *count);
                           ^~~~~~
```

Here `count` is already a pointer on integer, `*` is unnecessary:

```
return fib_rec(n-1, count)+ fib_rec(n-2, count);
```

#### display of computed value

Your code return the computed value, but doesn't display it.
To do so, replace `return fib_rec(n, &count);` with

```
printf("fib_rec(%d) = %d\n", n, fib_rec(n, &count));
return 0;
```

---

So the corrected code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fib_rec(int n, int *count);

int main(void) {
    int n;
    printf("enter n\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int count = 0;  // counts the number of times the function is called
    printf("fib_rec(%d) = %d\n", n, fib_rec(n, &count));
    return 0;

}

int fib_rec(int n, int *count)
{
    int b=0,c=1;
    *count = *count +1;
    if(n<=1)
    { 
       return n;
    }
    else
    {
      printf ("count: %d\n", *count);
      return fib_rec(n-1, count)+ fib_rec(n-2, count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**in `main`**

1. `main` has a prototype of `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, int argc *[])`. `fib` is not a valid input for `main`.
2. `main` will typically return `0`. So the line `fib_rec(n, &count);` should be put before the return.
3. variable `count` was not declared. Variable `m` is unused.
4. Before the `main` function the declaration for `fib_rec` should be there. `int fib_rec(int n, int *count);`

**In fib_rec**

5. Function for `printf` is not correct. - It should be `%d` with the `*count`
6. The recursive call is not correct, Since `count` in `fib_rec` is a pointer, it can be directly passed to the function again without taking the value. Like this - `return (fib_rec(n-1, count)+ fib_rec(n-2, count));`
7. Unused variable `b` and `c`

This solves the compilation issues. Code is below.

```
int fib_rec(int n, int *count);

int main(void) {

  int n;
  int count;
  printf("enter n"); 
  scanf("%d",&n);
  count = 0;  // counts the number of times the function is called
  fib_rec(n, &count);
  return 0;

}

int fib_rec(int n, int *count)
{
   *count = *count +1;

   if ((n<=1) )
   { 
      return 1;
   }
   else
   {
     printf ("%d ", n);
     return (fib_rec(n-1, count)+ fib_rec(n-2, count));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I request a way to only print the final value of count. I am confused if it is possible with this pointer-based approach.

Comment: Add `printf ("%d",count);` in main after the call to `fib_rec`. Just for your information, `count` in main is an integer. While `count` in the function `fib_rec` is a pointer to an integer.